# Check the disk space in Ubuntu (with ls)

Tags: ubuntu, ls, disk-usage, disk

I am using AWS Free tier Ubuntu. It is saying that disk space full in `/dev/xvda1` which is mounted on `/` . I am using `df` command to check it.

I went to the directory `/` and using command `ls -l` to check which file is taking much space. But, none of them is taking that much within `/` . What is the recommended way to find out which file is taking much space ?

I have attached the screenshot, please check it. You can see none of them is taking `99892768` space.

[image]

Comment: The size of the files, as displayed by `ls`, is only the size of the file itself: if the file is a directory, this will not include the size of the directory contents.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself and format it as code with the `{}` icon in the editor.

Comment: You may want to remove old kernel images with `sudo apt autoremove`, usually this solves a problem like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find find the largest files and directories that exist on your system, you can run:

```
du / | sort -n
```

The largest files and directories will be printed at the end. Use tail to find the nth largest:

```
du / | sort -n | tail -n 20
```

This will print the 20 largest files and directories on the system.

Answer (score 2):

`ls` does not show disk use for directories. As you can see all directories are shown as 4096B, which is clearly incorrect.

I suggest that you install `ncdu` by running `sudo apt-get install ncdu`, and then run `sudo ncdu /`.

This will show you the current disk use for the various directories, sorted by size.

Comment: No space left to even install this

Comment: Then go with `du -sh /*`, which is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l` does **not** provide full information about disk-space usage for directories. As you can see, all directories (per directory) have constant size, it means `4096`. If you want to see *sum* of directory usage, type:

```
du -sh /*
```

`du` is kind of tool that shows disk usage *per file*. `-s` means *summarize* and `-h` means make output human readable.

If you want to find *largest* file at `/var/` directory by example, I would try with that:

```
du -a /var | sort -n -r | head -n 10
```

References:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/du

Comment: @dessert Yes, of course. Edited. Thank you very much.

Comment: it is saying /var is taking much space. Now, how to find which file within /var ?